# Dataset Class Internal

Tags: c#, reflection, dataset

I am using reflection to call the forms in my software.
I have a library with normal classes, forms classes, and datasets classes.
I want to make only the forms accessible and usable from out side the library. 
Making forms, and normal classes internal is easy. 
But making datasets internal is harder than I thought. 
Is it even possible to make them internal? And if so how ?

I have a dataset called GendersDataSet. When I call the library by reflection and print out all the classes in it, I get this amongst others:

- GenderDataset
- GendersRowChangeEventHandler
- GendersDataTable
- GendersRow
- GendersRowChangeEvent

How do I make them invisible, or at least inaccessible to any class outside the library?

EDIT: edited some spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created a dataset using default VS provided templates (DataSet.xsd file). If you look into your solution, you will see a [DataSetName].Designer.cs file. Make the class in that file as internal. HTH

This will be needed on all the other supporting classes which are created. Although as Marc suggested, these values may get overwritten.

Comment: Tried that already... Made public key words into internal in both the dataset class and the designer. Doesn't work.

thank you for the response.

Comment: editing .designer.cs files is also prone to having your changes overwritten at random

Comment: @MarcGravell This can be done through designer too. We can set the modifier from properties window. Although this does not seem to apply to datatables etc.